# Deploy-url Fonts Angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using `ancgular-cli` to build my application and I have such command in production -

```
ng build --aot --target=production -e ${NG_ENV:-prod} --deploy-url ${NG_DEPLOY_URL:-https://app.contentsnare.com/} --output-path dist && find dist \\( -name '*.css' -o -name '*.js' \\) -exec gzip --keep --quiet --force {} \\;
```

, it all works well, but there is a problem in the connection of `glyphicons` fonts. 
They get the wrong path, the errors looks like this - http://joxi.ru/a2XYkX6syDb01A , don't understand why and how it can be fixed.

I think this is because of the deploy-url, but don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use static.json to deploy, or nginx then you should put this to the configs:

```
"headers": {
   "*/glyphicons-halflings-regular.*": {
     "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
   }
 }
```

For example, I use this buildpack on Heroku and I should write the following in static.json for it:

```
{
 "root": "dist/",
 "https_only": true,
 "routes": {
   "/**": "index.html"
  },
  "headers": {
    "*/glyphicons-halflings-regular.*": {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
   }
}
```